# Only Local Connections Allowed error for Internet Explorer Driver, On Selenium-webdriver

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer

I am currently attempting to setup Selenium Grid using javascript and selenium-webdriver. I have my hub and node setup and currently have run successful tests on Chrome and Firefox. However, I am running into some trouble setting up a test for Internet Explorer. Below is my test code that has worked for Chrome/Firefox. Just a test that pulls up Google and prints the title. The caps were added as a potentially fix for the bug, but hasn't worked.

```
const { Builder } = require("selenium-webdriver");
const ie = require("selenium-webdriver/ie");

(async function hello() {

    var caps = {
        'ensureCleanSession' : 'true',
        'ignoreProtectedModeSettings' : 'true',
        'forceCreateProcessApi' : 'true',
        'ensureCleanSession' : 'true',
        'ignoreZoomSetting' : 'true',
        'INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS' : 'true'
    };

    let driver = new Builder()
        .usingServer("http://XX.XX.XX.XX:4444/wd/hub")
        .withCapabilities(caps)
        .forBrowser('internet explorer')
        .build();
    try {
        await driver.get('http://www.google.com')
                    .then(() => driver.getTitle())
                    .then(title => console.log(title))
    }
    finally {
        await driver.quit();
    }
})();
```

The error I'm getting shows up on the command prompt in the node. Showing as follows:

```
Started InternetExplorerDriver server (32-bit)
3.150.1.0
Listening on port 42242
Only local connections are allowed
```

I've tried numerous solutions that I have found online:

- Changing the Internet Explorer security settings, to have protected mode be enabled on all levels
- Setting the Zoom to 100%
- Changing the driver to 32-bit
- Adding TabProcGrowth Registry

Nothing seems to work, so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: For the Selenium, only version 11 is supported, and it requires additional configuration: 1. The IEDriverServer exectuable must be downloaded and placed in your PATH. 2. "Enhanced Protected Mode" must be disabled for IE 10 and higher. 3. For Windows 10, you also need to set "Change the size of text, apps, and other items" to 100% in display settings. 4. For 32-bit Windows installations, navigate to the registry editor: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE`, inside this key, create a DWORD value named iexplore.exe with the value of `0`.

Comment: More detail information, you could refer this link: [Required Configuration](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#required-configuration).

Comment: I still could not get this to work unfortunately, so I ended up switching to Microsoft Edge. I am running into a different problem with that browser however, and so I posted a different question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67377150/attempting-to-using-selenium-grid-to-run-test-with-microsoft-edge-sessionnotcre