# Attempting to using Selenium Grid to run test with Microsoft Edge, SessionNotCreatedError

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge

I am currently attempting to setup Selenium Grid using javascript and selenium-webdriver. I have my hub and node setup and currently have run successful tests on Chrome and Firefox. However, I am running into some trouble setting up a test for Microsoft Edge. Just a test that pulls up Google and prints the title.

```
const { Builder } = require("selenium-webdriver");
const edge = require("selenium-webdriver/edge");
let opts = new edge.Options();

(async function helloSelenium() {
    let driver = new Builder()
        .usingServer("http://XX.XX.XX.XX:4444/wd/hub")
        .forBrowser('edge')
        .setEdgeOptions(opts)
        .build();

    try {
        await driver.get('http://www.google.com')
                    .then(() => driver.getTitle())
                    .then(title => console.log(title))
    }
    finally {
        await driver.quit();
    }
})();
```

The error I'm getting shows up on the command prompt in the hub (nothing shows up in the node). Showing as follows:

```
(node:8956) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SessionNotCreatedError: Unable to create session from {
  "desiredCapabilities": {
    "browserName": "edge",
    "se:CONFIG_UUID": null
  },
  "capabilities": {
    "firstMatch": [
      {
        "browserName": "edge"
      }
    ]
  }
}
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'MDEV', ip: 'XX.XX.XX.XX', os.name: '....', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_291'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at Object.checkLegacyResponse (C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\sel-testing\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:553:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\sel-testing\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:634:13)
    at Executor.execute (C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\sel-testing\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:568:28)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
(node:8956) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 3)
```

I haven't found much regarding the usage of Microsoft Edge in JS Selenium Grid, so I've come here to ask for help.

Any assistance would be appreciated!

**EDIT**

I tried using the Node Config as suggested by Yu Zhou, and am now getting a different error: `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SessionNotCreatedError: Unable to create new service: EdgeDriverService`

I attempted to use a different function that uses @microsoft/edge-selenium-tools instead of selenium-webdriver like so:

```
const edge = require("@microsoft/edge-selenium-tools");

let options = new edge.Options().setEdgeChromium(true);
let driver = new edge.Driver().createSession(options);
```

When run, this does create an Edge session, however I have not found a way to send this to my Selenium Grid. Can someone help me to do so, or offer guidance with the new error on my old code?

Comment: Are you using Edge Chromium? If so, you can try to use [this Node config](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/8712#issuecomment-695793782) in this GitHub thread which will make it work with Grid 3. There're many related threads: [thread1](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/8671), [thread2](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/7567), you can also refer to. Besides, you can also check the [official doc](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/grid/grid_3/setting_up_your_own_grid/) about setting up selenium grid 3.

Comment: Posted an edit after taking your node config suggestion

Comment: How do you start the hub and node? The new issue seems to be caused by not using right path location of edge driver to start the node (don't pass it in the .json file ). You need to pass the absolute path of EdgeDriver when you start the node, like this: `java -jar -Dwebdriver.edge.driver=your/path/to/msedgedriver.exe selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role node -nodeConfig nodeConfig.json`.